# PHP foreach loop: loop one more time after certain condition is matched

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel and trying to get value of an array after another value using foreach loop. I am wondering what would be the best practice in solving this problem. So far I have tried this

```
$problems = $request->session()->get('problems');
$i = 0;
foreach ($problems as $prob) {
   $problem = $prob;
   if($request->problem_id == $prob->id){
         return 'Matched';
         die(); 
    }  
    $i++;  
}
```

Comment: so in an array of like `[1,2,3,4]` if you have the value 3 you want the 4th element?

Comment: _Side note:_ You can remove the `die();`. Since you have a `return` before it, it will never get triggered.

Comment: @ Sérgio yes, exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your foreach in something like that

```
$shouldQuit = false;
foreach ($problems as $prob) {
   $problem = $prob;
   if($shouldQuit)
       break;
   if($request->problem_id == $prob->id){
         $shouldQuit = true;
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @NooglersBIT Glad to hear that, don't forget to mark this at the answer.

Comment: You should probably just return or break inside the if statement, right now it will continue one more loop after a match was made.

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough @Lucarnosky code will work theres a faster way of handling this.

```
$problems = array_flip($request->session()->get('problems'));
if(key_exists($request->problem_id, $problems) return 'matched';
return 'problem not found';
```

[php key_exists function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key-exists.php)

[php array_flip function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)